# How to integrate Jersey into spring 5 mvc application without spring boot and springrest

Tags: java, spring-mvc, web, jersey

I have a problem with auto wired interface of UserSevice which always returns me a null value, due to (as I think) wrong implementation of jersey into my spring app. So I need a clear reference or example of spring 5 mvc with jersey 2.x
Thanks in advice!

Comment: useful [example](https://www.codepedia.org/ama/restful-web-services-example-in-java-with-jersey-spring-and-mybatis/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is just to extend my class which gonna be REST api implementation from SpringBeanAutowiringSupport class

P.S. main point was in configuring Spring 5 with jersey without

"artifactId" jersey-spring4 "/artifactId"

dependency, because it caused "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanDefinitionCustomizer"

As I understand, my app had some configs which are in conflict with this dependency and tried to get SPRING 4 class from my spring 5 application

Answer (score 0):

i have a running project which supports spring mvc 5x, jersey 2x, and jsf(primefaces)
here is the pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.fajar.latihanjsftemplate</groupId>
    <artifactId>latihanjsftemplate</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>latihanjsftemplate Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/apache-log4j-extras -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>apache-log4j-extras</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api -->
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId> <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId> 
            <version>2.0-m10</version> </dependency> -->



        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.primefaces/primefaces -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.15</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JERSEY AND SPRING -->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged/jersey-guava -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-guava</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.26</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
            <version>2.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-spring4</artifactId>
            <version>2.26</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-jaxb</artifactId>
            <version>2.26</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>jsftemplate</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

and this is the web.xml (3 servlets):

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
  http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1">
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/appconfig-root.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
            <param-value>omega</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>fajar-am</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>fajar-am</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>fajar-am</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/mvc/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>latihanjsftemplate.testmvc</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>

    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <!-- <filter> <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name> <filter-class>latihanjsftemplate.filter.WebFilter</filter-class> 
        </filter> <filter-mapping> <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name> <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
        </filter-mapping> -->

</web-app>
```

Comment: I've added dependencies as youu mentioned, but got error "NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/access/BeanFactoryReference;"